# "Anfassen" and "berühren"

Tags: word-usage, difference, verb, meaning-in-context

I would like to know which of the two verbs is used to tell someone that you're serious about not being touched. If he touches you the second time, something's going to happen to him. Someone told me that *anfassen* sounds stronger than *berühren*. Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Anfassen** is **to touch with your hands** without being overly gentle.

**Berühren** is **to touch (with something)** without gaining a hold in a very somewhat gentle manner.

The English phrase

> Don't touch me!

would be translated using "anfassen" unless you have a good reason to use the other verb.

Answer (score 6):

In that situation you would say:

> Fass mich nicht an!

*Berühren* is very unspecific - you can touch something or someone with every body part. While *anfassen* you can only something with your hands. Moreover, *anfassen* presupposes some willful objective, some goal that is to be reached by using the hands. You can't, for instance, say:

> Ich faßte ihn versehentlich an.

While

> Ich berührte (versehentlich) ihre Schulter mit meiner Hand.

is okay. Without "versehentlich" it is at least open, whether it was a wilfull act or not. Even if wilfull, *berühren* is not appropriate to describe some forceful or violent activity. As @Em1 correctly points out, berühren is good for tender, not very intense, and not long lasting, touches, at least when it is about living beings.

In physics, it's a bit different:

> Als das abstürzende Flugzeug den Boden berührte, zerbrach es und explodierte hernach.

Comment: It should be noted that you can actually say *Ich habe versehentlich ihr Bein angefasst (obwohl ich eigentlich ihren Arm anfassen wollte*. So you *can* accidentially *anfassen* something, but only if you willfully tried to *anfassen* something else.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Sure. Interestingly *Ich habe versehentlich ihn angefaßt.* you express just this. What a difference it makes when one switches two words!

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point out, that although the direct translation of

> Don't touch me!

is

> Fass mich nicht an!

this cannot be generalized in the meaning of the OP. `berühren` is generally possible as well.

Example:

> Wenn du mich noch einmal berührst, dann töte ich dich!

I guess the reason is psychosounding.

- `berühren` sounds rather soft and thus doesn't suit the harshness of a short, negated imperative: `Berühr mich nicht!` in harsh voice just doesn't work.
- `anfassen` sounds stronger, especially in this case because of the splitting which puts `Fass …` at the beginning of the sentence.